# Facebook Errors on itegrating facebook sdk in android app

Tags: android, facebook

I integrated facebook in my app. The errors i getting in in two cases:

1. when facebook.apk is installed in emulator.
   errors: A page comes up saying 
   ***error code 100
    invalid parameters***
   and then if i again press ok button then my app getting force close with nullpointerexception.

2.when facebook.apk is not installed in emulator.
errors:
  Although login page comes up but when i login
getting ***Force close***

Now i also try Example code come with facebook sdk.
i put my appId in example app.
Now while running the example app login occur after that when i click on post wall
the post wall page comes up and suddenly app goes disappear ***No ERROR*** in logcat.

I am doing this because my app is identical to example app provided by facebook.
(i copy paste the code from example app to my app).

Locat :
      10-14 16:30:02.176: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(218): Uncaught handler: thread main

```
  exiting  due to uncaught exception
  10-14 16:30:02.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(218): java.lang.NullPointerException
  10-14 16:30:02.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(218):     at       com.android.myapp.MyActivity$SampleAuthListener.onAuthSucceed(MyActivity.java:280)
  10-14 16:30:02.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(218):     at     com.android.myapp.SessionEvents.onLoginSuccess(SessionEvents.java:78)
  10-14 16:30:02.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(218):     at com.android.myapp.LoginButton$LoginDialogListener.onComplete(LoginButton.java:95)
  10-14 16:30:02.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(218):     at com.facebook.android.Facebook$1.onComplete(Facebook.java:308)
  10-14 16:30:02.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(218):     at com.facebook.android.FbDialog$FbWebViewClient.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(FbDialog.java:133)
  10-14 16:30:02.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(218):     at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.uiOverrideUrlLoading(CallbackProxy.java:193)
  10-14 16:30:02.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(218):     at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.handleMessage(CallbackProxy.java:304)
  10-14 16:30:02.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(218):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  10-14 16:30:02.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(218):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
  10-14 16:30:02.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(218):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
   10-14 16:30:02.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(218):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  10-14 16:30:02.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(218):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
  10-14 16:30:02.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(218):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
  10-14 16:30:02.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(218):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
   10-14 16:30:02.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(218):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

any help to solve this problem any suggestion are most welcome...

***EDIT*** 
I tried with an another example similarly put my appId but same error is occurring this example is taken from [here](http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2011/02/28/30-minute-guide-integrating-facebook-android-application/)

[image]

*** I think problem is not in the code but in the app page.***

***EDIT NOTE***  ***I tried same application 20 or 25 days ago and it was working fine***

Comment: Post some code and Log cat traces..

Comment: i edited the question with logcat.

Comment: Strange Error..Can you post code??

Comment: Show the row that results in a NullPointerException

Comment: What is on `MyActivity.java:280` ?

Comment: public void onAuthFail(String error) {
        mText.setText("Login Failed: " + error);
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that problem in the Code you are using. Better change you facebook code recommended by Facebook team :

You need to Download code from here : [Facebook in Github](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk).

Then check this page for Integrating Facebook in you App : [Guide To Integrate you App in Android](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/).

If you need to post on the user's wall check this link :

[Post in Facebook wall without Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5280720/facebook-post-on-friends-wall-in-android/7744153#7744153)

Comment: My friend tell me that this is a facebook error as they are changing a lot in facebook and soon it will be corrected but don't know what exactly causing problem