# How to post a message on facebook friends wall in Android

Tags: android, facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Facebook post on Friends wall in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5280720/facebook-post-on-friends-wall-in-android)

I have made an app in which i am fetching list of my all **FACEBOOK friends**, now i want while i do click on any of the friend row then i will be able to post on his/her wall.

So what are the permissions i need to give and what type of code i need to write to do that,

Like: still i have given below *permission* and written below code *onListItemClick*

permissions :

```
         mFacebook.authorize(main, new String[] { "publish_stream",
        "friends_birthday", "friends_photos"  }, new MyAuthorizeListener());
```

Code:

```
  @Override

   protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    MyFriend friend = (MyFriend) this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);

}
```

*I am fetching FbId, name, bday and picture*

```
 public class MyFriend {
private String fbID = " ";
private String name = " ";
private String bday = " "; 
private String pic = " ";

}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Now on-wards you can not post to our friend's wall.

Because Facebook has removed the feature from its *`Graph Api`*, so that we *`cannot Post on Friend's Wall`*

thats why we can only post on our facebook wall only.

Comment: Do you have official declaration for not supporting the "Post on Friend's Wall" by graph api?

Comment: @SomnathMuluk no brother but all other all code is not working...

Comment: here is official declaration  https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/10/10/platform-updates--operation-developer-love/

Answer (score 3):

Feature of posting on friend's wall has been removed from the Facebook sdk.

Previously it could have been done by the following code as claimed by this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7744153/1626878),

```
 try{
    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    JSONObject attachment = new JSONObject();

    try {
        attachment.put("message", "Messages");
        attachment.put("name", "Get utellit to send messages like this!");
        attachment.put("href", link);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
    }
    parameters.putString("attachment", attachment.toString());
    parameters.putString("message", "Text is lame. Listen up:");
    parameters.putString("target_id", "XXXXX"); // target Id in which you need to Post 
    parameters.putString("method", "stream.publish");
    String  response = authenticatedFacebook.request(parameters);       
    Log.v("response", response);
}
catch(Exception e){}
```