# Can't post message to friend facebook wall in android

Tags: android, facebook

I tried many ways to post a message to friend wall but no success:
[Post on user's friends facebook wall through android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5896863/post-on-users-friends-facebook-wall-through-android-application#answer-5898193) 

 [Post message to facebook wall from android fb sdk always error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726429/post-message-to-facebook-wall-from-android-fb-sdk-always-error/3927541#3927541) 

I also tested my account id and friend id aren't block from facebook, they can post message together in browser.
Here is my try:

```
    try { 
    Bundle params = new Bundle();

    params.putByteArray("message", "Test".getBytes());
    params.putByteArray("name", "American Virgin".getBytes());
    params.putByteArray("link", "http://bit.ly/12345".getBytes());
    params.putByteArray("description", "A Freshman College Girl on a scholarship from an ...".getBytes());
    params.putByteArray("picture", "http://xxx/MOV1026.jpg".getBytes());

    mAsyncRunner.request(((friendId == null) ? "me" : friendId) + "/feed", params,  new WallPostRequestListener());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But it response error:

```
 {"error": {"message":"An access token is required to request this resource.",
    "type":"OAuthException","code":104}}
```

Then I tried to add token to the parameter but not work

```
     params.putString(Facebook.TOKEN, mFacebook.getAccessToken());
```

The problem is I can login success without error.
So, I need the right way to post a message to friend wall that worked for me.

Comment: you able to post on your own wall?

Comment: Yes, I can, I don't know where I am wrong

Comment: Can you post using the Graph API Explorer? https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer By the way in the future the ability to post to a friend's wall via the Graph API is going away soon (https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/10/10/growing-quality-apps-with-open-graph/) so you don't want to build that into your app.